# ASP.NET CORE w/ NEST/Elasticsearch.net: custom contract resolver

Tags: c#, asp.net, elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net

```
public ISearchResponse<object> GetById(string id) {

        var uri = new Uri("<myendpoint>");

        var settings = new ConnectionSettings(uri).DefaultIndex("useraction-*").PrettyJson().DisableDirectStreaming(); //or try _all
        var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

        var search = new SearchRequest<object>
        {
            Query = new TermQuery
            {
                Field = "field",
                Value = "example"
            }
        };

        var response = client.Search<object>(search);

        return response;
    }
```

I'm having trouble getting NEST to work. When I try to call the query defined above, I get the following error:

```
System.Exception: If you use a custom contract resolver be sure to subclass from ElasticResolver
at Nest.JsonExtensions.GetConnectionSettings(JsonSerializer serializer) in C:\Users\russ\source\elasticsearch-net-master\src\Nest\CommonAbstractions\Extensions\JsonExtensions.cs
```

I've searched the internet for mention of this and can't seem to find anything other than the source code. I've pretty much followed the documentation exactly so I don't know what to change.

Does anyone out there know what this error is trying to tell me? I feel like it's an error behind the scenes that I don't have control over.

I'm happy to answer additional questions if people need more info.

Thanks.

Also I don't know where that path is coming from in the exception because I have no user "russ"

Comment: russ is me :) What version of NEST are you using and what version of Elasticsearch are you running against?

Comment: Oh, sweet! I'm using NEST v5.0.0-alpha3 and Elasticsearch v2.3

Comment: NEST 5.0.0-alpha3 is not compatible with Elasticsearch 2.3; the major versions are NEST are compatible with the major versions of Elasticsearch so you should grab the latest NEST 2.x, which at this time is NEST 2.4.5. Try with that and let me know if you still see the issue